# steps for making a non-distributed db to distributed db [talking about lmdb specifically]

Tags: python, distributed-database, lmdb

I am dealing with lmdb and lmdb is really fast . But one problem with it is lmdb isn't distributed . Everytime i need to do some maintenance , lmdb has to taken down and sites is unavailable for few hours .  I researching on making lmdb a distributed one , implementing replication capabilites . So far the closest i have been close to it a [dynomite](https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite) code base by netflix .
Issue with that it is currently applicable for redis and memcache ,but it say generic so it can be used for lmdb also .I am handling lmdb with python using [py-lmdb](https://github.com/dw/py-lmdb) bindings

I am out of clue how to approach it from lmdb perspective in python world , since code has to be written in python bindings also .

Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 4):

LMDB is meant to only be an embedded DB engine. Distribution/replication belong to a higher layer. You could use HyperDex with the LMDB backend, for example. https://github.com/hyc/HyperDex/tree/lmdb. There's also memcachedb built on LMDB, and ardb or ledisdb for redis-compatible servers running on top of LMDB.

https://gitorious.org/mdb/memcachedb/source/9f2e5415e4d9017889caf61c100a9b8652825319:

So you could use them with dynomite if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can drop LMDB (embeded in ARDB) to replace Redis in Dynomite to make LMDB a distributed system. We have done a POC on this and they worked.

For more information, you can look into our opening issues at https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite/issues/254

Comment: Thanks, looks like dynomite is evolving at constant pace.